# What is the risk of committing .npmrc file and exposing to the world?

Tags: credentials, node.js

I have seen multiple projects committing .npmrc file along with rest of the files. Are the auth credentials npm credentials? What is the risk if an attacker gets hold of the credentials? As npm requires 2 factor auth is the risk low?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing this file in the web directory is very serious and generally makes pentesters or bug bounty researchers very happy.  The auth token allows you to make API calls directly to NPM to list packages, delete packages, publish new packages, list users and group names, and a number of other things.  Even if you have MFA enabled it will only prompt you for package publish API calls and automation tokens will ignore MFA completely! https://docs.npmjs.com/about-access-tokens

Additionally, in my experience, tokens are almost always very over-permissioned and allow write operations when they probably shouldn't.  We see this broadly across all access token types during pentest engagements.